# looking for a cloud operating system to install on my own hardware

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud

is there something like that?
I've been told that IBM has one (IBM cloud burst)
anybody knows ?

Comment: Which hardware?

Comment: @Massimo servers and anything else the cloud os might need

Comment: What are you trying to do? "Cloud" is usually used to mean computing-as-a-service, running on hosted hardware that you don't own or maintain. It's about easy provisioning to the customer, usually via a lot of automation by the provider. It's certainly not a new operating system.

Cloudburst is just Websphere bundled into an appliance that runs RedHat.

Do you want to run an application in a "cloud", or do you want to build a cloud for other people to be able to run their stuff? It's one or the other, because if you're doing both, then you're maintaining systems and that's not really "cloud."

Comment: @mfinni thnx for your explanation, I could accept this as an answer, actually I it's the government of my country (where I work) want's to implement cloud computing, and nobody actually knows what for they want to use it, but I do know that they want to install in on their own hardware

Comment: If you have no list of requirements, how can you meet them? You need to do a lot of work to define what's required before you pick and implement a given technology.

Comment: @mfinni I would like to know the possibilities, like what is it possible to do with this IBM cloud burst (for what is mostly used), can I put in there an asp.net application (like on windows azure) or is it just for whatever redhat linux can support

Comment: Not to be harsh, but why don't you look at the web page for IBM Cloudburst? It says the same thing I told you - it's for WebSphere. That's not going to run ASP.NET.

Comment: You can run the Azure fabric locally on your PC (Visual Studio includes it); you can't run an Azure fabric on  your local servers yet but I just read last night that they're working on something for that.
Besides that, there are a couple dozen vendors that say "here we have a 'cloud OS' you can run in your data center", including IBM, VMWare, Citrix and others, plus open source stuff like Eucalytpus.  It really depends what you actually want.  Here's a mind map of the hundreds of "cloud" offerings, it's a complex field... http://jldupont.blogspot.com/2009/02/cloud-computing-mind-map.html

Comment: do you actually mean virtulisation rather than cloud?

Comment: @EK isn't this kinda the same thing, in particular atm I'm looking at the VMWare private cloud vSphere, which it's called a cloud, and I think it looks like virtualisation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might take a look at [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com/) and/or [Ubuntu's cloud pages](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud) if you're looking to get a demonstration project up & running quickly.

Comment: I found WMWare VSphere, it looks like a real cloud, it can run anything

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Azure there is the [Windows Azure platform](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/) AppFabric which helps developers connect applications and services in the cloud or on-premises. This includes applications running on Windows Azure, Windows Server and a number of other platforms including Java, Ruby, PHP and others. It provides a Service Bus for connectivity across network and organizational boundaries, and Access Control for federated authorization as a service.

There is also the "Windows Server AppFabric" which is a set of integrated technologies that make it easier to build, scale and manage Web and composite applications that run on IIS which is available at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx

Comment: I've found WMWare VSphere, it looks like a real cloud, it can run anything